# Use different typescript versions for different dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript

I've seen similar questions go unanswered on here so fingers crossed on this one..

I'm working on an Angular application where I have two dependencies, each specifying incompatible versions of typescript.

Is there any way to use a different typescript version for a specific dependency?

Comment: Maybe but it's not a good idea. It's like having two version of angular in the same project ( I'm not talking about angularjs and angular ). Maybe you could try to find another dependency that would work with the same version of typescript. Or check if there is an update for the dependencies that are problematics.

Comment: If you mean to code dependancies, this is impossible. Your application will be compiled through a single typescript compiler. Unless you did some magic by specifically excluding and including certain files. I would not recommend this. It would be a much better idea to work out why you need different versions in the first place and aim to fix that.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a different set of typings? Often it's just in the inclusion of new features that causes the incompatibility (using "unknown" or "Record"). If we could alter the .d.ts file, and include it in our project so that those typings are used, rather than the ones from the package in node_modules, it would be a big help. Any way to do that?